# Including my own js and css file in a vue cli3 project

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-cli

I have a couple of js and css files which were custom built and i want to include that into my vue cli3 project.
Is there any way to import those files into my project ?

Comment: `import x from y`?

Comment: may be you can import it in index file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom js files, write all your logic in a object and export it at the end of the file :

```
const customJs = {
   /* custom javascript here */
}

export default customJs;
```

and then import it where you need it as :

```
import * as customJs from '../path/to/file.js'
```

For custom css files, you can use `@import` between the `style` tags like this:

```
@import './../node_modules/foo/bar.css';
```

Comment: Do consider upvoting the answer as well, if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pre-processor when creating the project with vue-cli.

[See: Working with CSS](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#working-with-css)

Or if you don't need a pre-processor and you are using CSS modules you can go for this route

[See: CSS Modules](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules)

As for JavaScript it's pretty straight forward if you are on ES2016/ES6 just use the syntax

```
import tool from 'toolmodulename';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in main.js

import "path-your-css/your-css.css";